# Munich to Salzburg Round Trip - Blue Card

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, austria, munich, blue-card

I reside in Munich holding a Blue Card visa and would like to travel to Salzburg Austria for a long weekend (14th May).

I am confused as to:

- the legality (can I leave and get back in)
- Is there train or bus transport available during the current lockdowns in each country
- The situation around testing and quarantine
- Can I be stopped from returning to Germany since I only have a blue card and am not a EU citizen?

I have consulted some locals and got mixed messages, and have had trouble navigating the German, Austrian, and local government/ state websites to find a definitive answer.

Any advice would be immensely appreciated, vielen danke.

Comment: Since Restaurants and hotels in Austria are closed until the 18th of May, a long weekend in Salzburg on the 14th of May is not very practical. Starting the 19th the situation makes such a visit possible.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer regarding your third bullet point:

Quarantine rules on return to Germany will depend on how Germany classifies the pandemic situation in Austria, notably regarding mutant varieties ([Virusvarianten-Gebiete](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html)). This classification may change on short notice, even while you're already abroad. So better plan with the worst-case scenario of [14 days quarantine](https://www.gesetze-bayern.de/Content/Document/BayEQV/true) for a resident of Bavaria, and take it as bonus if you can get out earlier.

The German government strongly *advises* citizens and residents against travel to Austria. They don't do that lightly.

Comment: At the moment Austria is slightly lower (in the 7 day value) than Germany, but the concern expressed here is nevertheless valid.

Answer (score 0):

The rules in Austria will radically change on the 19th of May.

For the immigration side of the question, as a resident of Germany you may freely enter Austria and return to Germany.

At the moment there are about 32 daily train connections between the 2 cities.

Covid-19 conditions when returning to Germany will be based on whether you are **fully** vaccinated (or recovered) or not.

A test (and quarantine) is presenty **not required** for those who are fully vaccinated (or recovered).

The entry rules for Austria (starting on the 19th) have not yet been finalized, but it has been announced that vaccinated (or recovered) do not require a test or quarantine.
Note: the Austrian text does not use the word **fully**, so this is a bit ambiguous.

**Inside Austria**:

For visiting restaurants, hotels, culture and sport events, no test will be required for persons 22 days after they have recieved the 1st vaccination or have recovered.

This law has been finalized and comes into effect on the 19th of May.

Comment: Since OP is planning to travel on May 14th, it is of no relevance to the question of you tell him what will be allowed in Austria after May 19th.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Kindly read the comment in the main question that addresses that point.

Comment: Your comment on the main question does not solve the problem that this is not answering what OP is asking about.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo This answers 1) whether leave and return as a Blue-Card holder is possible 2) How many connections between the 2 cities 3) Covid-19 conditions for entry to Germany ; all of which are valid today or in 6 days time.

Comment: Yes, and with those three points (that was btw just the first half of your answer) you seem to indicate that travel is possible. In the second half of your answer you fill up with confusing and irrelevant statements about entering Austria after May 19th, which is of absolutely no relevance for the question instead of explaining what is relevant to know for OP.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Who appointed you a censor or quality manager? Do not **lecture others** just because you think it's not relevent. Your personal **opinion** is not binding to others. If you have a problem with this, [Travel Meta Stack Exchange](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/) is where such matters should be delt with.

Comment: All users here on Stackexchange are quality managers. They do their job by downvoting and then explaining to you in a comment why your answer is not helpful.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I'd suggest you read [Privileges - Vote down - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) again. When out of 5 points, 4 are covered (the 5th answered elsewhere) the 'provide sufficient information to be useful in answering the question' condition is not fullfilled.

Answer (score -2):

You don't write why you are going to Austria, but going for tourism on May 14th will not be possible.

Coming from Germany, you are currently after entering Austria required to quarantine for at least 5 days unless you are covered by any of the exceptions, which you as a tourist will not be. Hotels and restaurants are also closed.

New rules in Austria will take effect on May 19th.

Comment: (-1) This answer is not helpful because it does not address the 4 main points of the question: 1+4) whether leave and return as a Blue-Card holder is possible 2) How many connections between the 2 cities exist 3) Present Covid-19 conditions for entry to Germany